# Closed form of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{a^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my case, the sum is actually $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-a)^{(2a)^i}$$
I am confused because I find anything about this type of series online, and it seems like there ought to be a closed form of some kind. I noted that that each term in the exponent is the $i$th term of a geometric series, but I couldn't find any simplification from there.

For the record this is not homework. It's just a random little puzzle I found online.

Comment: What is the order of exponents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no closed form for these.  However, the series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^{a^i}$ for positive integer $a$ are studied: you might look up [lacunary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).